# Rating functionality

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

I'm trying to build a star rating functionality which is described in the following site:
http://kgoutam.blogspot.bg/2013/02/show-star-rating-as-salesforce-standard.html

I followed the steps in the site but instead of visualizing stars in the section I created in the Account object I see a drop down list with five numbers.
This is how it looks:[image]
I suppose the issue in the two static resource files

Here is the vf page code:

```
<apex:page id="page1" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Account" extensions="StarRatingController">
<apex:styleSheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OrgResource,'development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css')}" />
<apex:styleSheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OrgResource,'jquery.ui.stars.css')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OrgResource,'js/jquery-1.5.1.js')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OrgResource,'development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OrgResource,'development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryStarRatingPlugIn,'jquery.ui.stars.min.js')}" />
<style>
    .detailList{
        width:94%;
    }
    .pbBody, .pbBody a, .pbBody td, .lbBody a, .lbBodyDescription, .list .headerRow .noRowsHeader {
     border-bottom: 0 none !important;
    }
</style>
<apex:form id="form1">
    <apex:pageBlock > 
    <div id="ep" class="bDetailBlock bPageBlock secondaryPalette">
        <div class="pbSubsection">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="detailList" style="border-bottom:none !important;" >
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="labelCol">Rating</td>
                        <td class="dataCol col02">
                            <apex:outputPanel >
                                <div class="divRating">
                                    <apex:selectList value="{!rating}" size="1">
                                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!listOfRatingOptions}" />
                                    </apex:selectList>
                                </div>  
                            </apex:outputPanel> 
                        </td>
                        <td class="labelCol">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="dataCol col02">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>  

      <script>
         jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                 jQuery(".divRating").stars({
                    inputType: "select",
                    cancelShow: false,
                    disabled:true
                 });
                 $(".accountBlock").children().attr('class','');
                 $(".detailList").css('width','94%');
             });

      </script>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

a-OrgResource
b-jQueryStarRatingPlugIn
which I uploaded.

The issue is that whatever file I try to upload I get the same drop down list with five numbers.
I use the same code described in the site.

Please advise appropriate solution to have the rating star visualforce page display stars instead of numbers.

Thank you

Comment: pls include your visualforce

Comment: check your developer console for errors

Comment: @Guy
I've included the code you requested.

Comment: @Avidev9 no trace of errors

Answer (score 4):

if you literally followed the example and downloaded those files, then the `jquery.ui.stars.css` will be in the `jQueryStarRatingPlugIn` Static Resource and not in the `OrgResource` Static Resource.

So change

```
<apex:styleSheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.OrgResource,'jquery.ui.stars.css')}" />
```

to

```
<apex:styleSheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryStarRatingPlugIn,'jquery.ui.stars.css')}" />
```